# Relation between Intensity and Refractive Index

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

A beam with an intensity of $1 \;kW/cm^{2}$ is incident on a glass block $(n = 1.5)$.
Calculate the light intensity inside the glass for the angle of incidence of $\theta$.

Is there any relation between refractive index and intensity from this question?

Answer (score 1):

The [Fresnel equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations) give the relationships between the reflected/transmitted fields (or intensities) as a function of incidence angle.

Comment: Yes, and don’t forget the factor of 1/cos(refracted angle) to account for the increased width of the refracted beam, which dilutes the intensity.

Comment: @Gilbert If you do that, you also have to do similar for the incident wave too. Easier still, don't worry about it. Work out the reflected power per unit area (where the angle issue doesn't arise because it is equal to the incidence angle) and subtract that from the incident to get the transmitted.